# WGPU - Rust or С/C++?

Tags: webgpu, wgpu-rs

Please explain about the Wgpu library:https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu

The page says:

```
To use wgpu in C/C++, you need wgpu-native.
```

wgpu-native:https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu-native

I go to the wgpu-native github page, so it says that:

```
This is a native WebGPU implementation in Rust, based on wgpu-core.
```

Something I got confused - they write about C/C ++, and when you go to the page - they write again about Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`wgpu`](https://wgpu.rs/) itself is written in [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) and can be used as a rust crate / library.

However there are C / C++ - Bindings to `wgpu`, which are published as [`wgpu-native`](https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu-native). `wgpu-native` itself is also written in rust, but it exposes a C interface which allows this library to be integrated in a variety of other programming languages using [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface).

Additional information about how a rust library can expose C-Bindings is for example given in [this article](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/09/05/how-create-c-binding-rust-library#).